# Значение слова кощун в средние века

Tags: этимология, значения, история-языка

Современные словари определяют слово кощун как "насмешник, богохульник".
Однако в "Материалах для словаря древнерусского языка" Срезневского напротив слов кощуна, коштяна, коштюна написано "μύθος, λήρος, басня, вздоръ":

[image: басня, вздоръ].

Так что же означало это слово? В интернете много сомнительных источников, которые охотно принимают вариант перевода "миф" и утверждают, что с приходом христианства все эти "мифы" стали считаться в лучшем случае баснями и вздором, а в худшем случае - оскорблением религиозных святынь.

И все-таки, есть ли основания для перевода слова "кощун" словом "миф"? В какой степени можно их отождествлять? Можно ли, например, думать что у славян были мифы-кощуны о героях, подобные греческим? Или кощуны в лучшем случае были небылицами?

**UPDATE** В [Словаре русского языка XVIII в.](http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/11/sla21801.htm) обнаружил слово *кощунья*, несколько выпадающее из ряда слов производных от "шутка, насмешка":

> КОЩУ́НЬЯ, и, ж. (Един.) Гадалка, ворожея. *Вопрошающия особы болтливы, и для того объявляют такой кощуньѣ наперед всѣ свои чаяния; а она располагает свои отвѣты всегда по сим мнѣниям. Жив. 148.*

Comment: Кощунья, может быть, подруга кощея, а не кощуна?

Comment: А может это вариация на тему "хитрить, заниматься интригами", т.е. может здесь отсутствует "мистичность". Как например гадалка - пытается угадать будущее (не подразумевается "связь с духами"), а вещунья - как бы "знает" его (есть оттенок мистики).

Comment: Еще интересно сравнить с этимологией слова врач ("тот, кто врёт", аналогично ткач, рвач и т.д.). Тогда, кажется, у глагола "врать" тоже было какое-то граничащее с колдовским значение

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Согласно Фасмеру,

> Насмешник, богохульник, укр. кощун, болг. кощун, - то же, кощуня - "хитрю, интригую, насмехаюсь". Вероятно, от костить, так же есть толкование как заиствование из тюркско-булгарского, ср. соответствующее ему тат. koštan- "корыстный человек".

То есть приведённому Срезневским толкованию ничего не противоречит.

А вот логический вывод от смысла "басня, вздор" и далее, через "небылицу", в "миф" - это спекуляция чистейшей воды.

Мы очень мало знаем про дохристианскую Русь, есть большие основания полагать, что христианизация произошла и стремительно и жестоко, но трактовать так этимологию слова кощунство имея на руках те данные, что мы имеем сейчас - чистая спекуляция.

Comment: Но что Срезневский имел в виду когда писал греческие слова mythos, leros?

Comment: @Artemix, понимаете, у слова mythos в инзачальном варианте несколько значений, близких к "побасенка", "рассказ", может быть, "быль" - http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mythos - не обязательно это что-то пафосное. Что касается λήρος то это точно побасенка - http://www.oshkoshpresbyterians.org/happenings/sermons/2009-04-12-Laros

Поймите, что Срезневский тоже человек и сто лет назад требования к составлению словарей были менее жёсткими. Вполне возможно, что это он добавил сам, на своё усмотрение не слишком утруждая себя доказательствами.

Comment: Я согласен с вашим комментарием за исключением последнего предложения. Во-первых это "материалы к словарю", а не сам словарь (в котором, кстати, "кощуна" переводится как "святотатство; забавные шутки" - от "мифа" не осталось и следа). Во-вторых, похоже что слово mythos приведено из-за того что "кощуна" использовалось для перевода mythos с греческого. Впрочем, вряд ли с греческого переводилось что-либо кроме христианских текстов, поэтому скорее всего mythos в лучшем случае это некий рассказ.

Comment: ну как, с греческого как минимум переводилась вся греческая классика, но да, второе слово собственно нам и подсказывает что первое  - в значении рассказ. OK, требования к материалам к словарю тоже были менее строгими ;)

Comment: Греческая классика - да, но в какой момент мифы о Геракле к примеру, стали цениться переводчиками и заказчиками таких переводов? Возможно к тому времени уже появилось собственно слово миф.

Comment: @Artemix: late to the party, but in Sreznevsky's dictionary, Greek words in an entry mean that this entry was actually used to translate the corresponding Greek words: *Въ отношенiи перевода словъ на Греческiй языкъ, Измаилъ Ивановичъ предполагалъ приводить переводъ большею частью лишь въ томъ случаѣ, если можно указать, что именно это слово было въ томъ подлинникѣ, съ котораго сдѣланъ переводъ на древне-Русскiй или Старославянскiй языкъ*

Answer (score 1):

Ну так оттуда и кощунство, как насмешка над проповедью. А ведь кощУны - это те, кто «кости перемывали», так сказать насмехались и веселились, при этом говоря правду. Не кажется ли Вам, что они напоминают нам сейчас сатириков? И значит "кощуна" - это сатира.